# esp32 higher timer frequency and lower clock divider

Tags: timer, esp32

I'm measuring with the esp32 very short time intervals for the load curve of a small capacity. Is there a way to increase the clock frequency of timer? I tried out to change the clock frequency of cpu. It works but it had no effect at the clock frequency of timer.
I also have tried out to reduce clock divider. I figured out that the lowest allowed value is 2. Could I use the timer without frequency divider? My timer config:

```
timer_config_t config = {
  .alarm_en = TIMER_ALARM_DIS,
   .counter_en = TIMER_AUTORELOAD_DIS,
   .intr_type = TIMER_INTR_LEVEL,
   .counter_dir = TIMER_COUNT_UP,
   .auto_reload = TIMER_AUTORELOAD_DIS,
   .divider = 2 // 1 / 250 ns per tick
};
```

A few weeks ago I asked a similar question but it was only about changing clock frequency and not timer frequency.